# Fragment to fragment shared element transition is not working when exit

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I suspect that its happening because of transition name is not set but im unable to detect that is it the reason or there is another reason or what I'm doing wrong or what is missing, here is my code:

on click of recyclerview item: i didn't set transition name in on bind view if i do it also don't work

```
 holder.iv.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage");

                MainActivity.position = position;

                ImagePagerFragment productDetailFragment = new ImagePagerFragment();
                productDetailFragment.setEnterTransition(R.transition.image_shared_element_transition);
                productDetailFragment.postponeEnterTransition();

                getActive.getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .addSharedElement(holder.iv, holder.iv.getTransitionName())
                        .replace(R.id.fragment, productDetailFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

in ImagePagerFragment:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  prepareSharedElementTransition();
  postponeEnterTransition();
}
```

prepareSharedElementTransition();:

```
 Transition transition =
    TransitionInflater.from(getContext())
        .inflateTransition(R.transition.image_shared_element_transition);
setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
setEnterTransition(transition);
setEnterSharedElementCallback(
    new SharedElementCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
        Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter()
            .instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        View view = currentFragment.getView();
        if (view == null) {
          return;
        }
        sharedElements.put(names.get(0), view.findViewById(R.id.image1));
      }
    });
```

adapter on viewpager simply returning a fragment, ImageFragment, in ImageFragment in picasso success callback:

```
 ivZoom.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage");
  getParentFragment().startPostponedEnterTransition();
```

for exit ImageFragment i have button on button click:

```
 close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                  ivZoom.getTransitionName();
              }
          }, 500);

      }
  });
```

and on exit transition is not working

onBind of recyclerview adapter:

```
  Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageArrayList.get(position).getUrl())
```

//                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)

```
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_tall)
            .fit().centerCrop()

            .into(holder.iv, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                       // holder.iv.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                       // holder.iv.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408748/shared-transition-doesnt-work-recyclerview-to-fragment/42409362#42409362

Comment: so what I'm missing, I'm tired of it :(

Comment: What supportLibrary version are you using ?

Comment: @AkshayMahajan  v7 -26.1.0

Comment: Just try to debug and see whether source and destination transitionNames are same.

Comment: when i return to adapter of recyclerview holder.iv.getTransitionName is null

Comment: Ok, I think I know what the problem is, you need to postpone and start the return transition as well in your `RecyclerView` adapter when you set the image with Glide or Picasso, are you doing that?

Comment: how, could you answer?

Comment: Can you show me the piece of code in your `RecyclerView` adapter where you set the images in `onBindViewHolder` using Glide or Picasso

Comment: Ok, we'll try, if it works, I'll post it as an answer :) in your `onBindViewHolder` in Picasso callbacks put `startPostponedEnterTransition` and in your **Fragment** that contains the `RecyclerView` put `postponeEnterTransition`.

Comment: And when you `startPostponedEnterTransition` in the Adapter you will need an instance of your **Fragment** so that you can do `fragment.startPostponedEnterTransition()`, you can pass this instance through the Adapter constructor.