# How to anchor simple button to snackbar

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-snackbar, floating-action-button

I have button instead of floating action button i want to anchor it with snack bar as it anchor with floating action bar like floating action button moves up when snack bar is shown, with floating action bar we do it like this:

```
Snackbar.make(fab, s, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

how can I do with simple button as snackbar and button don't know snackbar presence and vice versa and moves independently

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to attach a `Behavior` to the `View` you want to move along with `Snakebar` movement

In here I make a custom `View` and attach the behavior to it

```
@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(CustomView.Behavior.class)
public class CustomView extends View {
    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public static class Behavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<CustomView> {

        public Behavior() {
            super();
        }

        public Behavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToLayoutParams(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp) {
            if (lp.dodgeInsetEdges == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) {
                // This setting makes it works (learn from FloatingActionButton.Behavior)
                lp.dodgeInsetEdges = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, CustomView child,
                                              View dependency) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Use this `CustomView` in your layout and it should work

The `FloatingActionButton` does the same thing, it has an inner `Behavior` which do many more things with the shadow padding, show/hide base on `AppBarLayout` movement. Every movement in `CoordinatorLayout` base on its `Behavior` mechanism

Ref here: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

**P/S**: About `Snakebar.make` usage, pass the `CoordinatorLayout` into `view` parameter, don't pass any other components, that will save the system performance. If you look at the `Snakebar` code, it has a loop, uses the view parameter to find the root view. The root view is what it wants:

```
private static ViewGroup findSuitableParent(View view) {
    ViewGroup fallback = null;
    do {
        if (view instanceof CoordinatorLayout) {
            // We've found a CoordinatorLayout, use it
            return (ViewGroup) view;
        } else if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            if (view.getId() == android.R.id.content) {
                // If we've hit the decor content view, then we didn't find a CoL in the
                // hierarchy, so use it.
                return (ViewGroup) view;
            } else {
                // It's not the content view but we'll use it as our fallback
                fallback = (ViewGroup) view;
            }
        }

        if (view != null) {
            // Else, we will loop and crawl up the view hierarchy and try to find a parent
            final ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
            view = parent instanceof View ? (View) parent : null;
        }
    } while (view != null);

    // If we reach here then we didn't find a CoL or a suitable content view so we'll fallback
    return fallback;
}
```

Comment: In code you provided where its state that button or view should move up with snackbar?

Comment: I updated the code with a comment, `Gravity.BOTTOM` is where it happens

Comment: Is `CoordinateLayout` your root layout? And do you pass it as param to `Snakebar.make(coordinatorLayout, ...)`

Comment: yes i did, as fab.getRootView(); fab is custom button also i extend Button instead of View in the code you provided

Comment: Ok the problem is you use `getRootView`, which will return the PhoneWindow.DecorView, the outermost container. This is the container of `CoordinatorLayout` so it cannot find one using current logic. Passing exactly the `CoordinatorLayout`, or the button itself should fix it

Comment: could you see my other post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597274/fragment-to-fragment-shared-element-transition-is-not-working-when-exit

Answer (score 1):

The Docs say this

> Having a CoordinatorLayout in your view hierarchy allows Snackbar to enable certain features, such as swipe-to-dismiss and automatically moving of widgets like FloatingActionButton.

So as you long as your button is directly under the Coordinator Layout and you pass the button to the Snackbar like this

`Snackbar.make(yourButton, s, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);` . The moving of widgets upwards should work.

Comment: its simple button not fab

Comment: It should work for any type of view because it takes an object of type view as parameter.

Comment: The `view` in `Snackbar` is used for finding the root view of the layout, the root view then in charge of showing the `Snackbar`, it's not used for moving that `View` up or down. The way `CoordinateLayout` translate FAB base on `Snackbar` movement is by its `Behavior` system

Comment: @TamHuynh could you answer

Comment: @blackHawk What do you mean? I did answer above, plus an explanation to the `view` param of `Snakebar.make`

Comment: So i need to add behaviour for button?

Comment: the below answer didn't work, could you suggest something